# Iphone - How to align the text justified (newspaper like) in Interface Builder

Tags: iphone, interface-builder, alignment, justify

Is it possible? Align the text fully justified? Does anyone know any hack or Interface Builder plugin?

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301519?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do it using UITextView, or any others. When I need justified text, I construct an html and show it in a UIWebView.

Comment: Ok EEE, thanks a lot. I will try this but the problem is that Im extracting the data from an RSS feed and the extracted text comes with a lot of line breaks. I´ve tried to remove them using \n and \r but it doesnt work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

[Here is the solution](http://didikot.com/?p=285) in my blog. I don't like use WebView. Also hyphenation word wrapper included.

Answer (score 1):

From the definition of [UITextAlignment](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UITextAlignment) it looks like you can't. Perhaps you can use the text drawing code to draw the text yourself, since you won't need interaction it shouldn't be *too* difficult.

Comment: Humn... But the text is dinamic, I get them from an RSS... Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using CoreText, yes, you will have a bit more of work, but it works like a charm. You can check [this](http://invasivecode.tumblr.com/core-text) tutorial for that.