# printing text as a paragraph(indentation) in uitextview in iphone

Tags: iphone, uitextview

A basic functionality I am trying to implement in `UITextView`.

I have a text (`NSString`) and I am trying to place in to the text field as a paragraph (indentation). Is it possible? I have seen many links but none of them have an exact answer.

We have a property named `textAlignment` but it is for left, right or center not indention.

Can anyone suggest how to implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should consider using a `UIWebView` if your displayed text has formatting. Using textViews and labels quickly renders the code to complex.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301519/justified-alignment-in-uitextview-iphone) - as the first answer suggested, use a [`UIWebView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html).