# NSString right and left justified text?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

How to do a NSString both right and left justified text?

thx

I tried  `@"%-10@"`  and `@"+10@"`  ... not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. An `NSString` is just a sequence of characters. It doesn't know anything about justification, or anything else related to formatting.

Comment: If I am using "CGContextShowTextAtPoint", how do I do this...thx

Comment: Or you can use OHAttributedLabel class, answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7379612/736384

Answer (score 0):

Fully justified text is not supported by UILabel/UITextView

But...

This should solve your problem.
[Sizing a UILabel to fit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406212/sizing-a-uilabel-to-fit)