# UILabel paragraph text alignment

Tags: objective-c, ios, uilabel, uitextview, text-alignment

I am working on an Iphone application and I need to display a large text. I need it to have a paragraph alignment. Please refer to the picture below for explanation.

I tried to use UILabel and UITextView but couldn't find the property to do it.

[image]

Comment: +1 for a clear concise, well illustrated question

Comment: Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7378409/uilabel-justify-left-and-right  it will help you,  it is similar to  your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [**TTTAttributedLabel**](https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel/downloads) NSAtributedString label which has UITextAlignmentJustify

```
 yourTTTAttributedLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentJustify;
```

Also another alternative is use  [**OHAttributedLabel**](https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHAttributedLabel) NSAtributedString label which has UITextAlignmentJustify

```
 yourOHAttributedLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentJustify;
```

Answer (score 2):

For ios  > 7.1 just set textAligment property to NSTextAlignmentJustified , without any third-part libraries:

```
UILabel *label = [UILabel alloc] init];
label.textAligment = NSTextAlignmentJustified;
```

Answer (score 1):

UITextView and UILabel they dont provide such alignment. You can use UIWebview instead.

You can use `<p style="text-align:justify">Your text goes here.</p>`

This might be helpful.