# Ends of lines getting truncated on iPhone ( EDIT : end of line justification)

Tags: ios

When I use a .txt file in my app (even when I fix it up as much as I can) The lines at the end get truncated. I want the text to reach the end of the line (all the way to the right side of the screen, just like the first line) . Should I use another type of file? If so, which? and if not, how do I get the words to reach the end of the line?

Thanks

p.s. cleantxt doesnt fix the problem
[image]

I want it to look like this

[image]

Comment: So you want the lines "justified"?

Comment: @Hot Licks  I edited the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I interpret your question correctly (via your example), this is not a question of truncation but a question of justification. You want "full justification" i.e. text stretching from left to right insets so the text appears as a rectangular block of text.

If yes and you are using a UITextView then:

For iOS 6 and earlier
UITextView *textView = @""; // replace with property representing the text from your .txt file
textView.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentJustified;

For iOS 7+ (above is deprecated)
You unfortunately need to either use CoreText or a UIWebView. 
See this post [Justified Alignment in UITextView](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5514950/3806828)

Comment: Thank you! you were right. I couldnt think of the word. What if I want it to work with both ios6 and 7?

Comment: I say go with the approach indicated for IOS7. Should work for both

Comment: I just tried the ios6 method you gave and it worked on my actual iPhone 4, ios 7.1.2!

Answer (score 0):

Do you get the same result using this code?

```
NSString *fileName = @"impressum.txt";
NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:[fileName stringByDeletingPathExtension] withExtension:[fileName pathExtension]];

NSError *error;
NSAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithFileURL:url
                                                                               options:@{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute:NSPlainTextDocumentType}
                                                                    documentAttributes:nil
                                                                                 error:&error];

CGRect paragraphRect = [attributedString boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(_textLabel.frame.size.width), CGFLOAT_MAX)
                                                          options:(NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin|NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading)
                                                          context:nil];

CGRect frame = _textLabel.frame;
frame.size.height = paragraphRect.size.height;
_textLabel.frame = frame;

[_textLabel setAttributedText:attributedString];
```